# How one can negate this statement?

Tags: logic

I have a logical satement of the form:

For every number $a≥0$, there exist two prime numbers $p$ and $p+2$ such that $$a+4<p<2^{a+4}$$ and $$a+4<p+2<2^{a+4}$$

Then how one can negate this statment?

**My solution**:

**There exist** a number $a≥0$ such that **for every** natural number $d$ with $$a+4<d,d+2<2^{a+4}$$ **at least** one of $d,d+2$ is **composite**.

Comment: Almost, but for your $d$ it could happen that $d+2$ was too big.  You want $a+4<d$ and $d+2<2^{a+4}$.

Comment: @lulu: we have $p+2$ in that interval

Comment: I am speaking of your negation.  It could happen that $2^{a+4}\pm 1$ are both primes but that would be irrelevant for current purposes.  You should only look in the given interval, so you need to require that both $d,d+2$ are in the interval.

Comment: @lulu: yes.  i unerstand this.

Comment: So...that condition must be added to your negation.  I suggested one way to do that.

Comment: @lulu: Ok added.

Answer (score 2):

**There exist** a number $a\ge 0$ such that **for every** twin prime numbers $p$ and $p+2$,

$$a+4\ge p$$

or

$$p \ge 2^{a+4} \tag 2$$

or

$$a+4\ge p+2 \tag 3$$

or

$$p+2 \ge 2^{a+4}$$

(One may omit inequalities $(2)$ and $(3)$ if they wish to)